# Unix: Looking to run a script in directories with a certain name

Tags: bash

I am writing a script in bash.

If I am in directory Foo, I want to run this script in only the subdirectories of foo that are named foo with up to three numbers after foo.

Ex: foo1, foo23, foo345 etc..

Test is the name of my script.

This is what I have so far. I cannot remember how to specify exactly what directories I want this script to look for.

Other things of importance: I am running on ssh client.

```
for i in foo*
    do                 
        if [ -d $i ]   
            then
               sh ./test 
               echo "Test is working."
        fi
    done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *right* way to do that is making the script take the directory as a parameter:

```
for directory in foo*/
do
    ./test.sh "$directory"
done
```

The trailing slash in the `for` loop ensures that it loops over directories and symlinks to directories. Passing the directory to the script ensures that you can move the script and the target directory *anywhere* without doing anything special to make it work.

To be more specific with regards to selecting directories, you'll want to read about [globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob), especially the section about `extglob`.

Comment: First, thank you for your help. How would I specify that only to certain subdirectories though? Would I use regular expressions?

Comment: Also, thank you for your explanation too, that really helps.

Comment: Edit: I understand and get it now. Thanks again!